# How can I keep a language selection active when clicking on other links within a website?

Tags: php, wordpress

Swapping out my question with the solution. Took me literally ages, but I managed. So for anyone who wants to use a language selection option on his/her website without using plugins, can use the below code. Hopefully it can help others save some time. ;)

Main navigation menu (in Wordpress/Elementor add this into a html-widget):

```
<div class="main_nav_menu">
  <a href="Link 1" class="menu-item">Home</a>
  
  <div class="menu-item with dropdown">
    Products <span class="arrow">▼</span>
    <div class="nav_submenu">
      <a href="Link 2" class="submenu-item">Product 1</a>
      <a href="Link 3" class="submenu-item">Product 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  <a href="Link 4" class="menu-item">Contact</a>
  <a href="Link 5" class="menu-item">About us</a>
</div>
```

Here the Java script to put an eventlistener to all the menu-items and once a link is clicked it adds the language parameter to the link (in Wordpress/Elementor add this below the html-code in the html-widget):

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
    // Get the main_nav_menu element
    var mainNavMenu = document.querySelector('.main_nav_menu');

    // Attach click event listener to the main_nav_menu
    mainNavMenu.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var clickedElement = event.target;

        // Check if the clicked element is a submenu item or a menu item
        if (clickedElement.classList.contains('submenu-item') || clickedElement.classList.contains('menu-item')) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var selectedLanguage = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get('lang');
            var link = clickedElement.getAttribute('href') + '?lang=' + selectedLanguage;

            window.location.href = link;
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here some CSS code proposals for visually adjusting the menu:

```
.main_nav_menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px !important;
  transition: background-color 0.8s, color 0.8s;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  color: #6e7384 !important;
  position: relative;
  /*transition: background-color 0.8s, color 0.8s;*/
}

.arrow {
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  transition: background-color 0.8s, color 0.8s;
}

.main_nav_menu .menu-item with dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.nav_submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #212b4d !important;
  width: 320px !important;
  transition: opacity 0.8s, transform 0.8s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.main_nav_menu .menu-item with dropdown:hover .nav_submenu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.submenu-item {
  display: block;
  color: #6e7384 !important;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  transition: background-color 0.8s, color 0.8s;
}

.submenu-item:hover {
  background-color: #181f3a;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Create an additional menu, where you can select the language (separate html-widget), which essentially does nothing else than adding the parameter ?lang=en/de/fr to the URL:

```
<div class="lang_menu">
  <div class="lang-dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="lang-menu-item">Lang</a>
    <div class="lang_submenu">
      <a href="?lang=en" class="submenu-item">EN</a>
      <a href="?lang=de" class="submenu-item">DE</a>
      <a href="?lang=fr" class="submenu-item">FR</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS code for the language menu (adjust the way you like it).

```
.lang_menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 40px !important;
  transition: background-color 0.8s, color 0.8s;
}

.lang-menu-item {
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  color: #6e7384 !important;
  position: relative;
}

.lang-menu-item:hover {
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  transition: background-color 0.8s, color 0.8s;
}

.lang-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.lang_submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #212b4d !important;
  width: 60px !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.lang-dropdown:hover .lang_submenu {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-item {
  display: block;
  color: #6e7384 !important;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  transition: background-color 0.8s, color 0.8s;
}

.submenu-item:hover {
  background-color: #181f3a;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Create your own little language.php plugin file for Wordpress and copy the following code into a separate folder where all your other plugins reside. This piece of code essentially will pick up the language parameter from the URL and will use shortcodes to display according content from the english/german/french/...language file.

```
<?php
    
    /*
    Plugin Name:    My Language Plugin
    Description:    Dropdown menu on website allows to select a language, which triggers the automatic population of the site content in that according language.
    Version:        1.0
    Author:         My Name
    Example:        [my_constant="Title"] > define("Title","This is the displayed title!");
    */
    
    // Start the session
    session_start();
    
    if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
        exit;
    }
    
    // Get the full path to the languages folder
    define('LANGUAGE_FOLDER', __DIR__ . '/');
    
    function constant_shortcode($atts) {
        $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
            'name' => '',
        ), $atts);
    
        $constant_name = $atts['name'];
        
        // Get the selected language from the URL parameter or fallback to default (English)
        $_SESSION['selected_language'] = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en';
            
        $language_file = LANGUAGE_FOLDER . 'language_' . $_SESSION['selected_language'] . '.php';
            
        if (!file_exists($language_file)) {
            $language_file = LANGUAGE_FOLDER . 'language_en.php';
        }
    
        include_once($language_file);
    
        if (defined($constant_name)) {
            return constant($constant_name);
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
    
    add_shortcode('my_constant', 'constant_shortcode');
    
?>
```

In the same folder as your language.php file you can add now for each language you want to use on your website a separate php file. Example: language_en.php, language_de.php, language_fr.php

How do these files look like inside?

language_en.php will have the whole list of short codes/translations for English:

```
<?php
        define("Title","This is the displayed title!");
?>
```

language_de.php will accordingly have all shortcodes for the German language. One example:

```
<?php
        define("Title","Dies ist der angezeigte Titel!");
?>
```

Your language.php file will add the shortcodes and based on the selected language the respective file will be sourced to display in case of the exmaple shortcode [my_constant="Title"] either "This is the displayed title!" for the English language or "Dies ist der angezeigte Titel!" for the German language and so on.

Comment: @wouch — Since PHP doesn't have access to sessionStorage, it's not a good use case at all. PHP sessions would make more sense. The OP says their tried them … but hasn't provided a [mcve] or any debugging information about the attempt.

Comment: I had the code line "session_start();" added in the working php-code and then further down "$selected_language = isset($_SESSION['selected_language']) ? $_SESSION['selected_language'] : 'en';", but that will make the code not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I hope these explanations make sense. I have very little experience with php/java script programming, therefore this might not be the most efficient approach, but it finally worked for me after hours of trying around...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).